# Why I cannot pull gitlab repo even though I created an SSH key?

Tags: linux, ssh, git, gitlab

I did everything required [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html) to create and issue my SSH key to GitLab. I both have a win64 PC and I use the Ubuntu 16.04.4 cluster at my research lab. With the PC this works and I am able to clone the repository without any problem. With the linux cluster (which I have physical access to but I also occasionally remote access it) however, I get the following error:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:gitlab_group_name/Projects/project_name.git
Cloning into 'project_name'...
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 57: Bad configuration option: xauthlocaion
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is this because I am not a superuser at the linux machine?

Comment: Does `git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlab_group_name/Projects/project_name` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As explained in this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/785297/100013), it seems as if you have an SSHD config option (`PermitRootLogin`) in your SSH config file (`ssh_config`) around line 57. As explained in that answer:

> `PermitRootLogin` is actually an option which is valid in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file; not the `ssh_config` file. The difference is that the `sshd_config` file controls the SSH server and the `ssh_config` file controls the client. Therefore, it would indeed be a bad (invalid) config option in the client settings file.